# Error when using the spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

When opening a spreadsheet using the spreadsheet gem, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:73:in `block in encoding': Unknown Codepage 0xc24a (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:72:in `fetch'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:72:in `encoding'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:197:in `read_codepage'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:788:in `read_workbook'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:122:in `read'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/workbook.rb:32:in `open'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:62:in `open'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spreadsheet-0.6.5.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:68:in `open'
from worksheet_demo.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What code led to the error? My best bet would be that you are trying to open a password-protected spreadsheet. In that case, try removing the password protection and see if it works.

Comment: yes, you are right. but i don't know how to remove the password protection in spreadsheet. Please help me if you know

Comment: Just posted more information as an answer :)

Comment: How would one do this programatically within ruby for example with a file upload on a rails site?

Answer (score 1):

This is symptomatic of trying to open an Excel spreadsheet that is password-protected. You can solve this problem by using the following steps to remove the password:

1. Open the workbook.
2. On the File menu, click Save As.
3. On the Tools menu, click General Options.
4. In the Password to open or Password to modify box (or in both boxes), double-click the asterisks and then press the DELETE key.
5. Click OK, and then click Save.
6. Click Yes to replace the existing workbook.